# Change CSS style on hyperlink click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the style on anchor tags using jquery, once the link is clicked.

```
<tr class="row-tab" style="height: 30px;">
    <td class="subtab-selected"><a href="#" id="as1">TOP % GAINERS</a></td>
    <td class="subtab-notselected"><a href="#" id="as2">TOP % LOSERS</a></td>
</tr>

$('#as1, #as2').click(function(){
    $('#as1, #as2').parent().removeClass('subtab-selected').addClass('subtab-notselected');

    $('this').parent().addClass('subtab-selected');

    return false;                  
});
```

I'm trying to change the CSS class when a link is clicked but the second line of the jquery code does not get executed.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to change the class of the link or of the <td> that contains the link?

Comment: As written, the clicked anchor's parent would have both classes ('subtab-notselected' AND 'subtab-selected') applied.

Answer (score 6):

Try removing the quotes around `'this'`

Comment: No, did not work. The first line of code gets executed. The class gets removed and other class gets added. 
But the second line of code does not work.

Comment: That's exactly what your code does as written.  Can you give us more details about what you want it to do?

Comment: I want the code to add the class 'subtab-selected' on the link(td) clicked and remove it from the other link and then add the class 'subtab-notselected' to it.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a solution without the fixed `#ids` on the jQuery:

```
$("td a").click(function() {
    var p = $(this).parents("tr");
    $("td", p).removeClass("subtab-selected").addClass("subtab-notselected");
    $(this).parent().addClass("subtab-selected");
    return false;
});
```

You can see it runing [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/4LTeg/).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing that second line to:

```
$('this').parent().addClass('subtab-selected').removeClass('subtab-notselected');
```

I assume you wouldn't want both.

Comment: Thanks, removing the other class was required. And you are right I do not need both classes. Just need one at a time.

Comment: No problem. By the way, you can make things a little cleaner by using toggleClass("subtab-selected subtab-notselected")

Comment: Toggle will not work in my case, as if the tab is already selected and we select it again it will change that class. I do not want that to happen.